# Join tables by timestamp and date columns?

Tags: abap, opensql

I should retrieve data from two log tables (`BALHDR` and `ZIF_LOG_XML_CONTENT`). My problem is that the only commonality between the log tables is the time when the entries were created. The query has to work for a PERIOD and not for a TIME POINT.

However, the time for the entries is not stored in the same format in the two tables. In `ZIF_LOG_XML_CONTENT` it is stored in one column `TIMESTAMP` in the other log table in the `BALHDR` it is stored in two columns, where `DATE` and `TIME` are stored separately.

I tried to transform all the times to `STRING`, but still not working...

What am I doing wrong?

```
DATA: GV_DATEANDTIMETO TYPE STRING,
      GV_DATETO     TYPE STRING,
      GV_TIMETO     TYPE STRING,
      GV_DATEANDTIMEFROM TYPE STRING,
      GV_DATEFROM   TYPE STRING,
      GV_TIMEFROM   TYPE STRING,
      GV_DATUM      TYPE STRING.

SELECT * FROM BALHDR INTO @GS_MSG_STRUKT WHERE
        EXTNUMBER = @P_EXTID AND
        OBJECT    = @P_OBJ AND
        SUBOBJECT = @P_SUBOBJ AND
        ALUSER    = @P_USER AND
        ( ALDATE_BALHDR >= @GV_INPUT_DATETO AND ALTIME_BALHDR >= @GV__INPUT_TIMETO ) AND
        ( ALDATE_BALHDR <= @GV_INPUT_DATEFROM AND ALTIME_BALHDR <= @GV__INPUT_TIMEFROM ) AND
        MSG_CNT_E >= 1 OR MSG_CNT_AL IS ZERO.

     concatenate GS_MSGTABLE-DATE GS_MSGTABLE-TIME into GV_DATUM.

     SELECT RES_CONTENT, REQ_CONTENT 
        FROM zif_log_content 
        INTO @GS_MSG_STRUKT 
        WHERE TIMESTAMP >= @Gv_date AND TIMESTAMP <= @Gv_date. 
     ENDSELECT.
ENDSELECT.
```

Comment: This won't work as the TIMESTAMP in SAP is a decimal type and does not equal to a concatenation of the date and time in any way.

Comment: Beside your question, a remark about your code: in the way you use `SELECT`...`ENDSELECT`, this form is obsolete, you should do only one `SELECT` with a join.

Comment: I am sry, but I am really new in abap world. I try to explain my problem again. I sould compare balhdr~date and balhdr~time (they are two colums) to zif_log_content~timestamp colum for a user defines intervall. From the balhdr I have to select  EXTNUMBER, DATE, TIME OBJECT, SUBOBJECT, ALUSER, MSG_COUNT_ALL, MSG_COUNT_ERROR  and from the second table for the same time intervall I sould have two column, RESPONSE_MSG and REQUEST_MSG. That what my select sould do. Can you please help me to undestand and write this?

Comment: Hi, Sandra, where is it marked as obsolete? This is a perfect way of doing an `OPEN CURSOR` without an `OPEN CURSOR`.

Comment: @ErzsébetGombkötő If you post a fully working minimal example, then I will be able to help you.

Comment: @Jagger I said "in the way you use it, it's obsolete", I didn't say that it's always obsolete.

Comment: What version of ABAP and DBMS do you use? For 7.4 and above you can create AMDP method for class and do all the SQL stuff here without compatibility limitations (as matching types etc): in SQL you can cast almost anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenating works, you just need to pass timestamp into your SELECT, not string.

Here is a working simplified example based on standard `BALHDR` and `MBEW` tables:

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF struct,
         lognumber TYPE balhdr-lognumber,
         aldate    TYPE balhdr-aldate,
         altime    TYPE balhdr-altime,
         timestamp TYPE mbew-timestamp,
       END OF struct.

DATA: gs_msg_strukt TYPE struct.
DATA: gt_msg_strukt TYPE TABLE OF struct.

SELECT *
  FROM balhdr
  INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF @gs_msg_strukt
  WHERE aldate >= @gv_input_dateto AND altime <= @gv_input_timeto.

  CONCATENATE gs_msg_strukt-aldate gs_msg_strukt-altime INTO gv_datum.
  DATA(gv_date) = CONV timestamp( gv_datum ).

  SELECT timestamp
    FROM mbew
    INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF @gs_msg_strukt
   WHERE timestamp >= @gv_date AND timestamp <= @gv_date.
  ENDSELECT.

  APPEND gs_msg_strukt TO gt_msg_strukt. "<---move APPEND here
ENDSELECT.
```

Comment: Hi Suncatcher, Thanks for the example. It's almost perfect, but I still have an issue. Even if there in no entry in the mbew for the selected timestamp I would still like to list all entries from the balhrd table. With your example if there is no corresponding entry is the mbew table then i got no output form either of the tables. Could you please help me with this issue? Much appreciated!

Comment: Just move out the APPEND from ENDSELECT and you will always get output if exists in BALHDR. Updated the code

Answer (score 1):

This won't work as the TIMESTAMP in SAP is a decimal type and does not equal to a concatenation of the date and time in any way.

You should create your time stamp using the following sentence.

```
CONVERT DATE gs_msgtable-date TIME gs_msgtable-time INTO TIME STAMP DATA(gv_timestamp) TIME ZONE sy-zonlo.
```

Be careful also with the time zone. I do not know in which time zone your entries in Z-table are. In the BAL table they should be stored in UTC. Be sure to check it before.

Comment: I got a syntax error:The data type of the component DATE of GS_MSGTABLE is not compatible with the data type of RES_CONTENT.

Comment: It is hard to say, without having a reproducible example from your side, but I guess there is something wrong with your projection `RES_CONTENT, REQ_CONTENT`, because I do not use `RS_CONTENT` is not used in my conversion in any way.

Comment: also there is no `aldate_balhdr` field in `BALHDR` table, you use presumably some odd view. That's why it is always useful to reproduce your problem on standard tables, this way others much more likely help you

Answer (score 0):

QUESTION

I haven t got a fully working minimal example yet, but I can give you an example for the the two tables, which I would like to join together. The third table shows the wanted result. THX

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
                               BALHDR
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | EXTNUMBER|   DATE   |   TIME |OBJECT|SUBOBJECT|  USER|MSG_ALL   |MSG_ERROR
 |---------------------------------------------------------------------------
A|  1236   |2000.10.10 |12:33:24 |KAT   |LEK      |NEK   |    NULL  | NULL
B|  1936   |2010.02.20 |02:33:44 |KAT   |MOK      |NEK   |    3     |  1
C|  1466   |2010.10.10 |11:35:34 |KAT   |LEK      |NEK   |    2     |  0
D|  1156   |2011.08.03 |02:13:14 |KAT   |MOK      |NEK   |    3     |  0
E|  1466   |2014.10.10 |11:35:34 |KAT   |LEK      |NEK   |   NULL   |  NULL
F|  1156   |2019.08.03 |02:13:14 |KAT   |MOK      |NEK   |    1     |  1


 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
                          ZIF_LOG
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |       TIMESTAMP |    REQ                  |    RES
 |---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1|  20100220023344 |      he                 |hello
2|  20101010113534 |      bla                |blala
3|  20110803021314 |      to                 |toto
4|  20190803021314 |      macs               |ka
```

The following table shows the wanted result. The nummbers from 1 to 4 and the letters from A to F are to helps to understand how the fields would correspond with each other.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
                               WANTED RESULT TABLE
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |EXTNUMBER|    DATE   |  TIME   |OBJECT|SUBOBJECT | USER|   REQ    |  RES 
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 A|  1236   |2000.10.10 |12:33:24 |KAT   |LEK      |NEK   |   NULL   | NULL
B2|  1936   |2010.02.20 |02:33:44 |KAT   |MOK      |NEK   |    he    |  hello
E |  1466   |2014.10.10 |11:35:34 |KAT   |LEK      |NEK   |   NULL   |  NULL
F6|  1156   |2019.08.03 |02:13:14 |KAT   |MOK      |NEK   |   macs   |  ka
```

THX